# changing time format from a mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored a date in my database and want to echo that date out using php. Have tried a few  things but can't get it to work. Any help appreciated!

```
<?php echo date('dd-mm-YY', $preview['upload_time']); ?>
```

Comment: It depends on _how_ they are stored.

Comment: hi, its stored as a timestamp in the database, default is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and the extra is set to on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP...thanks

Comment: Update your question with that information and tell us what you get instead of expected result. BTW, correct (day-month-year) format is: `'d-m-Y'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php echo date('dd-mm-YY', strtotime($preview['upload_time'])); ?>
```

Comment: See earlier comment on @Edwin Alex's answer

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() function.

```
<?php echo date('dd-mm-YY', strtotime($preview['upload_time'])); ?>
```

Comment: I strongly discourage use of strtotime. Many many problems have been solved in our company by eliminating strtotime.

Comment: Why @LuckySpoon? And what kind of problems?

Comment: @LuckySpoon I haven't faced any problems. I have been using from many years and in all my projects. I didn't face any problem

Comment: any other suggestions Lucky?

Comment: Personally, I push all our developers to understand the format they are coming from, and then convert via mktime. This means that you are self-checking format etc first, which gives you the ability to catch issues. If strtotime doesn't correctly understand what you're feeding in (a real issue for us here in Australia who don't follow US format dates), you'll get bizzare numbers come out which don't make a great deal of sense. Exploding the string to manually convert via mktime is more work I understand - but in my experience it's been something we've had to do. May be different inside the US.

Comment: @LuckySpoon In this case, however, `strtotime()` is taking a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from (presumably) a MySQL database so it would be very well suited and efficient for the job at hand.

On a side note I normally store all dates as UNIX timestamps (in UTC) so that the time zone +/- can be calculated separately -- very handy when you have multiple database servers located in different countries.

Comment: When I posted my comment, the OP hadn't mentioned how the date was stored in the database. If it's in something standard such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then I agree it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using this:

```
function getDTFromMysql($time){
    try {
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time) ;
    } catch (Exception $e) { return null ; }
    return $dt ;
}

$dt = getDTFromMysql($row['time']) ;  
echo $dt->format('dd-mm-YY') ;
```

There is some OOP, so you can use your [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) object how you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways :

First is change you syntax like this.

```
 <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($preview['upload_time'])); ?>
```

Second way is change format when you are fetching the data from database.

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(`YOUR_COLUMN_NAME`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `adddate` FROM.....
```

Hope this will helpful to you